# Magento - Need to force HTTP for two pages, and the rest of the website forced to HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, ssl

I have seen a couple of other people, also asked this question. I did not find any solution working out for me though.
So here is my problem:

On my Magento installation, HTTPS is forced for all pages, for security reasons. I wish to exclude two pages from this, so they are HTTP. It's two API PHP script/pages.

I'm quite lost at this point, but I hope someone will know more about this than me. I tried a couple of things in the `.htaccess` file, but no success. I really hope one of you guys can help me out!

Comment: Probably some .htaccess configuration. The question here is, why? Why remove security if its already there?

Comment: Because my supplier (which requires this API connection) do not support HTTPS, but only HTTP, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't - Magento routes everything through itself (even index.php) to retrieve the relevant assets. If you attempt to push it back to http when the *Unsecure -> Base URL* is set to https it'll just route it back through a 301.

Comment: @CD001 Oh, I don't hope that is the case, cause then I have no idea about what to do, heh!

Comment: Might be worth migrating this to http://magento.stackexchange.com/ ... more likely to get the specific knowledge there - I've not been using Magento for a *huge* amount of time.

Comment: "I have seen a couple of other people, also asked this question. I did not find any solution working out for me though" Why didn't those solutions work? "I tried a couple of things" What did you try? It's helpful to show that for others to use as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This forces everything to HTTPs except for the directories that you specify within the brackets:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force everything to HTTPs
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#Checks if HTTPs is on for foobar & foobar2, if it is, turn it off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(foobar|foobar2)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace foobar & foobar2 etc with the directories you wish to exclude. However, if your magneto installation already forces everything to HTTPs, then you only need the second part of this Rewrite:

```
#Checks if HTTPs is on for foobar & foobar2, if it is, turn it off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(foobar|foobar2)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It did not work out, I added this in my htacces file: `#Checks if HTTPs is on for foobar & foobar2, if it is, turn it off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(/codeswholesale/ReceivePreOrders/receivePreOrders|/codeswholesale/UpdateStockAndPrice/updateStock)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: This is also in htacces file, could that conflict with your code? `#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gaming4real.dk/codeswholesale/ReceivePreOrders/receivePreOrders/$1 [NC,L,R]



#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/https:\/\/gaming4real\.dk\/codeswholesale\/ReceivePreOrders\/receivePreOrders [NC]
 
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/https:\/\/gaming4real\.dk\/codeswholesale\/ReceivePreOrders\/receivePreOrders [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]`

Comment: You seem to be using very long directories. It should look more like `(receivePreOrders|updateStock)`

Comment: Yes, looking at the code you've posted it is forcing those to HTTPs, comment them out and test using the force HTTPs and the forced HTTP for specific files.

Comment: I tried to update the directories, and also deleted the other code for testing, without the other code, and yours in, it still forces to HTTPS.

Comment: I'm still fairly convinced this approach won't work for Magento because the `Mage` app itself will redirect after anything that happens in `.htaccess`... in theory you could circumvent Magento with a custom API that talks to the database without starting `Mage`.